# ColdFusion: how can I decrypt a value that was encrypted by another platform using the same Algorithm, Mode, Key, and IV?

Tags: encryption, coldfusion

Using PHP mcrypt_encrypt, text 'I am secret text' using tripledes, key 'xICbEwgvNMv7yyXIB4xbRUXxaGf4wnpP', Mode CBC, NoPadding, Base64, IV 'MDAwMA=='.

result:7lctMAo8uH/XRlbD82Yjclg2AT4EoR9+

-- or you can use any online tool to encrypt using these settings

Using CF encrypt, text 'I am secret text' using tripledes (DESEDE), key 'xICbEwgvNMv7yyXIB4xbRUXxaGf4wnpP', Mode ECB, NoPadding, Base64.

encrypt( 'I am secret text','xICbEwgvNMv7yyXIB4xbRUXxaGf4wnpP','DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding', 'Base64', ToBase64('0000'))

result: 1K1LPndpIEVLL6cNBMxCXw==

The result from CF seems will never match the output form another tool. Resulting in never being able to use CF decrypt on encrypted data sent to CF for processing. I have tried various combinations and algorithms.

why you ask do i want to do this?

Someone that is sending us sensitive information decided they want it extra secure.
Yes communicating over https.
The text is within a json file.
No, I do not feel like creating our own or using a third party tool to encrypt/decrypt on each of or ends.

Using encrypted text sent from outside CF within decrypt function over and over and over and over again with various algorithms and modes.

Using basic AES we often get message of "Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption." when trying to decrypt.

Yes we are using same key and modes, etc., on both ends.

I am completely flexible on the algorithm and mode. I would just love to see one of them work.

Comment: The result of the PHP code is achieved when the key is UTF-8 encoded and shortened to 24 bytes (PHP implicitly truncates a key that is too long), and additionally PKCS#7 padding is applied, s. [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Triple_DES_Encrypt(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'xICbEwgvNMv7yyXIB4xbRUXx'%7D,%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'MDAwMA%3D%3D'%7D,'CBC','Raw','Raw')To_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D')&input=SSBhbSBzZWNyZXQgdGV4dA).

Comment: In the CF code, pass `ToBase64('xICbEwgvNMv7yyXIB4xbRUXx')` and `'DESEDE/CBC/PKCS5Padding'` in the 2nd and 3rd parameters of `encrypt()` to get the same result, s. online on [CF Fiddle](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=d510c2a5-2208-4608-b06d-a2ed07a76432/5bc6cbf2-d237-4bc7-abdd-9269d21092f8/9d5e485a-c238-4d3b-a2e6-42b251cf5bd7.cfm).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco)

using ToBase64() around the key solved the issue.

```
Decrypt( encryptedMsg, ToBase64(key), "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", 'Hex')
```